# Writing data to another hard drive when using Bittorrent Sync

Tags: mount

I'm probably making a noob mistake, but i was basically trying to learn how to mount another hard drive for use with Bittorrent Sync.

Here is what is DID

Went into the terminal to create my folders and mount my drive:

```
sudo mkdir /media/MyFolder

sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/MyFolder
```

Now, compared to Windows where administrators identify drives as Letters, it mentioned that the Hard Drives appear as part of the file system.

Now, theory wise, what i really wanted to do was write data to my /dev/sdb1 drive, but instead it added data to my /media/MyFolder drive on my primary Operating System Drive.

What would enable me to "mount" my hard drive into the system so that the data gets written on my /dev/sdb1 drive?

Answer (score 0):

After you mounted your disk under `/media/MyFolder`, all the directory hierarchy that appears under `/media/MyFolder` will physically reside on the other disk. You can see this with the command `df`. For example:

```
(0)samsung-romano:~% sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/tmp 
(0)samsung-romano:~% df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[...]
/dev/sda6       480G  192G  265G  42% /home
/dev/sda2       3.7G   30M  3.5G   1% /mnt/tmp
```

Look --- the `sda2` partition has 30M used. Now if I copy a large file (around 1.9G) under `/mnt/tmp`:

```
 (0)samsung-romano:~% sudo cp tmp/00032.MTS /mnt/tmp
```

Then I have:

```
(0)samsung-romano:~% df -h | grep sda 
/dev/sda1        88G   11G   74G  13% /
/dev/sda6       480G  192G  265G  42% /home
/dev/sda2       3.7G  1.9G  1.6G  55% /mnt/tmp
```

See? The big file is now on the other disk. If I u(n)mount the disk, now, the bigfile will be invisible.

Look:

```
(0)samsung-romano:~% ls -l /mnt/tmp/*.MTS
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2006482944 Dec  6 21:24 /mnt/tmp/00032.MTS
(0)samsung-romano:~% sudo umount /mnt/tmp
(0)samsung-romano:~% ls -l /mnt/tmp
total 0
```

Notice: I had to use `sudo` here because the permission of the mounted disk. You should use a bit more complex command to mount the disk and make it available to write to it as a normal user --- but that would be another question (probably already answered somewhere).